# Induced homomorphism and the fundamental group

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

The following question is taken from J. Munkres's Topology, second edition, of chapter 9 on the fundamental group, exercise 4.

Let $A\subset X$; suppose $r:X\to A$ is a continous map such that $r(a)=a$ for each $a\in A$. If $a_0\in A$, show that
$$r_{*}:\pi_1(X,a_0)\to \pi_1(A,a_0)$$

is surjective. Here $r_{*}$ is homomorphism induced by $r$, and defined by $r_{*}([f])=[r\circ f]$.

My attempt: For my understanding, an element of a fundamental group is an equivalence class of homotopic loops. To show surjectivity of $r_{*}$ one need to show that for any $[f]\in \pi_1(A,a_0)$, there is $[g]\in \pi_1(X,a_0)$, such that $r_{*}([g])=[f]$. But $[f] = [r\circ f]$, hence is enough to take $g=f$. I have doubts on this argument, and asking for your guidence. Thank you.

Comment: What doubts do you have?

Comment: The argument is fine. To make it a little more formal write $i:A\hookrightarrow X$ for the inclusion. Then $id_A=r\circ i$ implies that $id_{\pi_1A}=(r\circ i)_*=r_*\circ i_*$. (so you would take $[g]=i_*[f]$ to have things be neater).

Comment: @ConnorMalin: Thank you very much for this insight.